# Is it possible to build a Linux/Motif Eclipse RCP application?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, rcp, motif

I am trying to build an Eclipse application that would work with a linux/motif installation target.  However, this seems not to be possible even though the export option is available in the product export wizard.

I've checked the content of the delta pack and indeed, the packages for linux/motif are missing.  After checking the downloads page for eclipse 3.4 at:
http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.4-200806172000/index.php

I see that even though there is an Eclipse version marked for Linux/motif, it is marked as ***Testing only***.  Additionally, there is no delta pack for this target.

Has anyone been successful building an RCP application targeting linux/motif?  Would it work if I download this testing only version of eclipse and copy the missing plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a similar issue. We are building Eclipse applications and one of our platforms is Solaris 10 x86 which was supported for a short time as an early access build in 3.2 and dropped. I believe 3.2 and 3.3 supported motif so your best bet may be to revert to an older version of Eclipse. I develop in 3.4 and when we do the Solaris specific release we switch back to 3.2, it is usually about 10 minutes of changes to fix everything for the prior version. Usually it is removing @overides in a few locations and changing a function or two that Eclipse no longer uses.

The other thing you can do is get the Linux/Motif package for Eclipse, and install it on a Linux box running Motif. Check out your project on that Eclipse machine and export it there. I tried out VirtualBox (a free Virtual Machine from Sun Microsystems) it should make this easy for you.